# How can I forward the HTTP and SSH port to my internal server using iptables?

Tags: ssh, iptables, routing, http, port-forwarding

I do not have the router so I made my CentOS 6.4 Linux system into a router, forwarding the public network traffic to my local LAN.
It has two NIC cards, one for the public IP address (eth1) and another for the private IP address (eth2).

I have a server connected to my local LAN, let's say at `192.168.1.2`.

### Router

- eth1: `x.x.x.x`, the public IP address
- eth2: `192.168.1.1`, the internal router address

When someone from an outside network runs ssh on the public IP, it should be redirected to the server:

`ssh x.x.x.x` or using [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY)

I disabled the SELinux and iptables firewall on the server.
I tried some iptables modifications on the Linux system router, but the SSH request is still not redirected:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:22
```

I also want to forward all HTTP (80) traffic to my internal server using iptables from the same Linux system router.

Comment: Can you provide your iptables -L output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all make sure the packet forwarding is enabled in the kernel

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You can also make it permanent by adding below line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

You have to do this on Linux Machine acting as a router. You can try the following rule on router machine.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 22 -j  DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:22
```

Also let us know the output of your NAT Rules from the router box.

```
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

Comment: Yes, just replace the port number. Use 80 for HTTP

Comment: Hi, sandeep i want one thing that in my server i made a apache webserver. i want to access the particular site which is hosted on server. how i can do this. on browser http://publicip:80/path to directory but not accessible.help me.

Comment: Try to first open the site from your LAN http://192.168.1.2/path then see what happens. If you are still facing issues, I suggest opening a new thread with detailed problem description explaining what have you configured with Apache.

Comment: pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination          `  0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2222 to:192.168.88.2:2222 `  but can not port forwarding?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this amazing [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables#adjusting-the-permanent-rule-set)'s tutorial about how to forward ports, I decided to re-write it here.

I spent many hours of research about how this works.. I'm new to linux and beginnings aren't always easy.. Here is example of my servers and it's port forwarding:

Firewall server (2 NIC cards) - network details:

- Public IP address: **xx.xx.xx.xx**
- Private IP address: **yy.yy.yy.yy**
- Public interface: **eth0**
- Private interface: **eth1**

*Internal* (e.g. ssh, web) server (1 NIC card) - network details:

- Private IP address: **zz.zz.zz.zz**
- Private interface: **eth0**

Solution:

Enable packet forwarding in kernel:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Define variables:

```
# Admin IP address (e.g. public home ip)
ADMIN="aa.aa.aa.aa"

# IP addresses of servers (e.g. in cloud):
FW_eth0_ip="xx.xx.xx.xx"
FW_eth1_ip="yy.yy.yy.yy"
WEB_eth0_ip="zz.zz.zz.zz"

# Services:
SSH="22"
HTTP="80"
```

Iptables port forwarding (with -m conntrack):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s $ADMIN -d $FW_eth0_ip -p tcp --dport $SSH -j DNAT --to-destination $WEB_eth0_ip
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp --syn --dport $SSH -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport $SSH -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp --sport $SSH -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p tcp --dport $SSH -d $WEB_eth0_ip -j SNAT --to-source $FW_eth1_ip
```

Few notes:

- "..-s $ADMIN -d $FW_eth0_ip.." (1st row) - added only for security reasons - it means that only ADMIN IP can access SSH (if not needed you can delete it)
- *-m conntrack* is the same as *-m state*
- I recommend to change default port of SSH to another port, like 1xxxx (in /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
- check [List of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)
- I use port 15xx1 to access SSH on Firewall server, and 15xxx2 the Internal

Terminal:

```
# access firewall server
$ ssh sancro@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 15xx1

# access internal server
$ ssh sancro@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 15xx2
```

More details about used rules are perfectly described in mentioned tutorial.

That's all from me, hope it will help you.

Comment: # telnet 192.168.88.254 2222
telnet: cannot connect to remote host (192.168.88.254): Connection refused
# telnet 192.168.1.4 2222   
telnet: cannot connect to remote host (192.168.1.4): Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

First of all, enable routing in the Linux gateway:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then add the following rules with your network interface (i.e., eth1) and desired ports:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Check your rules with `iptables -L -v`, the pkts and bytes columns will show you which rules are being matched.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is about iptables, in case you also have FirewallD running, here's how to access HTTP of the internal network.

First allow http traffic in your internal server FirewallD:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
```

Then forward the http traffic from the external ip, to port 80 of the internal ip:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toaddr=10.0.0.11
```

Same thing can be done for SSH service.