# Iptables - centos 5.8 - how to forward ports to internal lan

Tags: centos, iptables, ip-forwarding

I'm trying to map port 8080 to another machine running a web server.

ppp0 = ADSL internet connection

eth0 = ethernet card of linux machine (ip address: 192.168.0.2)

192.168.0.105 = other machine with the web server

I want to forward requests on port: 8080 of ppp0 to 192.168.0.105:80 (other machine with web server)

(ppp0 is the ADSL connection of the linux machine - I have a dynamic DNS service for ppp0) 
So when I specify somewhere.no-ip.biz:8080 this request should go to 
192.168.0.2:8080 (linux machine that has ppp0 as ADSL connection) and forward to 192.168.0.105:80

I have the following iptable rule which I have no success with:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.105:80
```

Comment: I think you might need a rule to set up masquerading prior to this?  On the machine where I have this working I see something like: `/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXT_IF -s $INT_NET -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: Maybe this can help you --> http://serverfault.com/questions/564445/how-can-i-forward-the-http-and-ssh-port-to-my-internal-server-using-iptables